# How to set the size of tick label superscripts in matplotlib rcParams

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating some `.eps` files for a publication, and I need to manually set the font size of the the tick labels and their supercripts separately. The following code generates a figure where the exponent is too small for the final printed version.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 14

plt.semilogy(np.abs(np.random.randn(100)))
plt.savefig('foo.eps')
```

[image]

If I go into the output file and replace every line `9.799999999999999 scalefont` with `14.0 scalefont`, I get the following.

[image]

This is fine for now (I'm already processing the output files as part of the generating script), but I wonder if there's an `rcParam` entry that I can modify so that I don't need to directly muck around with the `eps` file as much.